# Compare a time field with a time range to determine the value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I need column C should check the time in column B and compare it with F and G column and display value from column E

Example : 8:30:01 AM   is between 4:30 am  and 12:30 pm  so it should return shift1 as a output in column C

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(B2,F:F)),"shift3")
```

[image]

---

For those with XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP(B2,F:F,E:E,"shift3",-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time getting comparisons to work on the time fields.  Can you use military time instead and just use the numbers,e.g. 133001 for 1:30:01 pm?  If so the following will work

```
=IF(AND(B3>$H$1,B3<$I$1),$G$1,IF(AND(B3>$H$2,B3<$I$2),$G$2,$G$3))
```